# Macro which will not compile the function if not defined

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

Currently using to show debug output when in debug mode:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define printX(...) Serial.printf( __VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define printX(...) NULL
#endif
```

yet this still include the printX in the result code, and the parameters which have been applied still consume memory, cpu power, and stack size, so my question is:

- is there a way to have a macro, which is not including the function, and "ignoring" all of it's calls in the source when in "release mode" and basically not compile anything with it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "still include the `printX` in the result code"? In the `else` branch, `printX(...)` with all its arguments is replaced with `NULL`.

Comment: Right... my stack went overflow then :D Thank You for the fast resetting it !

Comment: @Evg please put it as an answer so I can accept it since it's correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro

```
#define printX(...) NULL
```

replaces `printX` function call with all its arguments with plain `NULL`. This is a textual replacement that happens before a compiler is able to take a look at the code, so any nested calls inside `printX`, e.g.

```
printX(someExpensiveCall())
```

will also be completely eliminated.

Comment: Thank You. Sometime really the programmers get "stackoverflow", and my question was a good example of it. :D

Answer (score 2):

A macro is a not a function. It does not consume any memory, cpu power, or stack size. This is because macros operate entirely at compile time, and just act as a text replacing mechanism. When the program is run, there are no macros which are "called".

Answer (score 1):

In my programs I include a line that says:

#define DEBUG_MODE

and I use it anywhere I want to compile with (or without) debug mode:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    print here all the info I need for debug and certainly don't want in released binary.
#endif
```

Before releasing the final binary I comment out the definition line.